# Is there any way to store PDF made by chrome headless mode in RAM?

Tags: python, bash, shell, google-chrome, google-chrome-headless

I'm trying to change an **HTML to PDF** using chrome headless mode and I'm looking for a way to store the response in RAM instead of storing it on the disk but I couldn't find a way to do that. Is there any possible way to do that?

Comment: Can you clarify what do you mean by RAM ? Are you trying to get the output into a program variable (e.g., python, bash), or are you trying to avoid having the file being stored in a disk. What is the command that is use to get the PDF ?

Comment: i wanna get use the output as a program variable in python and i'm using chrome ```--print-to-pdf``` switch in bash - @dash-o

Comment: Can you provide more details. Assuming that you have the PDF file as a blob in Python, what will the code will do with it ? Do you plan to upload it to a remote location ?

Answer (score 1):

To solve your problem, you can use tmpfs:

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/tmpfs.5.html

tmpfs can mount a disk partition in RAM.

Answer (score 1):

Based on OP input - the goal is to get the content of the PDF into a program variable. There is no explicit problem limitation that will prevent using (temporary) file. The process will include the following steps
* Generate the pdf file
* Read the content of the file into (python) variable
* Remove the temp file

Coded uses 'page.pdf' as temporary file, but this can be modified to place the temp file in a different location.

```
import os ;
url = "http://www.yahoo.com"
# Use chrome, or whatever name needed to launch chrome on your system
os.system("chromium-browser --headless --print-to-pdf=page.pdf " + url) ;
with open("page.pdf", mode='rb') as file:
    data = file.read()
# Remove the file, if needed
os.remove("page.pdf")
# Do something with data, e.g., print the size
print("file size=", len(data))
```

Comment: i don't want the file to be stored on the disk at all. your solution stores the file on the disk temporally.

Comment: Note that a file is required to capture the output from chromium. PDF files can not be created directly to STDOUT. You can place the  file on /tmp, or on RAM disk /dev/shm (like the tmpfs proposal). Either way, I believe that you will need a file to exists for some short period of time.